# Classic ASP email script no longer working

Tags: asp-classic

I created a 'sendmail' script in ASP a few years ago, including email format validation and CAPTCHA validation. It worked well.

I've not received any enquiries through the form for a while now so thought I would test the contact page myself. Lo and behold, the script no longer seems to work.

Does anyone know if my method (please see below) has become obsolete over the past few years?! Is there now a different recommended way of doing this in (classic) ASP?

Here is the first part of my script (email addresses changed for privacy):

```
<%
Dim mail
Dim msgtext
Set mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
mail.To = "abcdef@ymail.com"
mail.Cc = "abcdefg@gmail.com"
mail.From = Request.Form("From")
mail.Subject = "Enquiry from website"

mail.TextBody = "From: " & Request.Form("Fname") & vbCRLF & "Message: " &  Replace(Request.Form("Body"),vbCrLf ,"") & vbCRLF & "Telephone: " & Request.Form("Phone") & vbCRLF


if not IsEmpty(Request.Form("btnTest")) then
    if TestCaptcha("ASPCAPTCHA", Request.Form("captchacode")) then
    else
        msgtext = "c"
    end if
end if

mail.Send()
'Destroy the mail object!
Set mail = nothing
msgtext = "y"
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that would leap out at me is that the default mail server might be stopped / not found.
From what I remember it's good practice to point to a specific server

```
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
    'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.server.com"
     'Server port
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
mail.Configuration.Fields.Update
mail.Send
set mail=nothing
```

Comment: I second this. A lot of web hosts now disable the local pickup and require use of SMTP to send messages, often through a centralised server, and sometimes even with user/password credentials. Try the code above, and if it doesn't work, ask your web host.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt you added Captcha last, so that would be the first thing to test by undefining its requirement. Also...

- You don't need () after "mail.Send".
- Check that your "From" variable is not empty.